# What is the difference between Cape Canaveral and Kennedy Space Center?

Tags: history, terminology, kennedy-space-center, cape-canaveral

Cape Canaveral and Kennedy Space Center are both at pretty much the same location in Florida. I do not understand why they are referenced separately in media.

How much are they separate entities? Is there any significant difference between the two? For example, are launches from each subject to different regulations for the launch provider?

Comment: I get confused as well. Now that everybody calls it what sounds to me exactly like "*[KFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KFC)*" I get even more confused.

Comment: ..throw in 'KSP' as well, and the confusion is complete:)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Supplementary answer:

Some of the confusion arises because there is also a *geographic feature* named Cape Canaveral.  It's pretty much the green area shown in [the other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28150), east of the Banana River.  On this geographic feature Cape Canaveral is built Cape Canaveral Air Force Station.  Today's Kennedy Space Center (KSC) is built on Merritt Island.

Even more confusingly, in 1963 then-President Johnson named the geographic feature Cape Kennedy and the NASA site after President John Kennedy.  (At the time what we now know as KSC was called the Launch Operations Center.) After the renaming we had Kennedy Space Center (not located on Cape Kennedy, but on Merritt Island) and Cape Canaveral Air Force Station (located on Cape Kennedy).

This drove the locals crazy, and in 1973 the state of Florida renamed the geographic feature Cape Canaveral, leading to the current situation.

And of course, in NASA parlance, "the Cape" is KSC.  *sigh*

Need more? There is a town named Merritt Island and a town named Cape Canaveral! Fortunately, these are located on the appropriately named geographic features.

| Year | Geographic Area | Facility | Town |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1962 |  |  |  |
|  | Cape Canaveral | Cape Canaveral Air Force Station | Cape Canaveral |
|  | Merritt Island | Launch Operations Center | Merritt Island |
| 1965 |  |  |  |
|  | Cape Kennedy | Cape Canaveral Air Force Station | Cape Canaveral |
|  | Merritt Island | Kennedy Space Center | Merritt Island |
| 2018 |  |  |  |
|  | Cape Canaveral | Cape Canaveral Air Force Station | Cape Canaveral |
|  | Merritt Island | Kennedy Space Center | Merritt Island |

Today there is *no such place* as Cape Kennedy! Be in the cool kids club by never saying that phrase.

References:

[Wikipedia: Cape Canaveral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral)

[Space.com: KSC](https://www.space.com/17705-nasa-kennedy-space-center.html)

Comment: Could you add what (if any) is the role of the Cape Canaveral Air Force Station in the whole space business? Why does the name Cape Canaveral appear so much in press reports etc, while Merritt Island is hardly mentioned?

Comment: Almost all the launch complexes / pads are on CCAFS property, only the old Apollo/Shuttle pages (launch complex 39) are on NASA property.  So practically all the launches are from CCAFS. There's a lot of overlap!  NASA missions like New Horizons launch from CCAFS complexes....and there was one badging office for both, my badges said "NASA / CCAFS".

Comment: When I visited there in 2011, it was explained that Kennedy Space Center was only used for manned launches and all unmanned launches (which are more numerous) occurred at Cape Canaveral Air Force Station. That of course was back when they were still doing manned launches from pad 39A with the space shuttle. Now 39A is used by SpaceX for unmanned launches as well, though they are working toward manned missions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Though the vast majority of manned launches have been from KSC, not CCAFS.

Comment: @reirab if you are responding to my comment, I was talking about the situation now, when there are no human spaceflight launches from the US.  Obviously the vast majority of US human spaceflight launches have been from Complex 39.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Gotcha. Yes, it was the "practically all the launches are from CCAFS" part to which I was responding. Makes more sense if just referring to the current situation.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, would fix, but it's a comment and timed out.

Comment: @Organic Marble: Copy comment text, paste in new comment and correct, delete old comment.

Comment: OK, this is all much too confusing. Can we all just agree to use the term "The Rockety Place in Florida"?

Comment: Now now, you can't deny "them" their acronyms. RPF, and RFP are already taken.

Comment: @reirab: Comments are comments, and in general shouldn't be added to answers.  Also (IMHO, anyway) it would be insufferably rude to edit someone else's answer without invitation.

Comment: @jamesqf Sorry, I meant the person you were replying to (Organic) could just edit the answer (which they wrote,) not you. I agree that editing someone else's answer to add information without their permission would be rude. In this case, the information in Organic's comment would be useful to the answer itself, IMO.

Comment: I'm trying not to step on the original answer which actually "answers that which was asked."

Comment: @OrganicMarble Fair enough.

Comment: [The most recent version of the CCAFS map (Nov 2017)](https://twitter.com/julia_bergeron/status/1017805270406352896)

Comment: The text says that the name change was in 1973, but the table implies that it was in 2018.

Comment: The table shows the state at three different dates. It implies nothing about when any changes took place.

Comment: @user47149 I like your edit, but the entries in the cells need to line up with each other like they did in the original. "Cape Kennedy" needs to be on a line above Merrit Island. Otherwise the meaning is lost. https://i.imgur.com/fdUn2z7.png

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did not know to pay attention to that. Thanks for explanation, for approving +2 point reward, and taking your time to prepare the PNG image showing what you mean. I will pay attention to such things in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 33):

Cape Canaveral is composed of two items, the Kennedy Space Center, run by NASA, and the Cape Canaveral Air Force Base, run by the Air Force. Because they are two very different organizations, the rules are quite different for each. See this map from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_Space_Center#/media/File:Merritt_Island.jpg) to show the different locations. Note that Kennedy (NASA) owns launch pad 39a and b, while the rest of the launch pads are owned by the Air Force in Canaveral.

[image]

Comment: You know that I had never quite gotten that piece of information... Sigh. Will edit appropriately.

Comment: Technically KSC is not on Cape Canaveral the geographic feature. KSC is on Merrit Island. The Cape iis everything to the east of the Banana River. See my supplementary answer.

Comment: So I guess I was right in the first place? Sigh... I give up.

Comment: Interesting to see that only the Kennedy Space Center has a USB port.

Comment: @curiousdannii The military doesn't like USB ports, due the providing a medium for easily exfiltrating information. So, that's probably why NASA has one and the Air Force doesn't. That, or because the DoD regs to approve the use of USB were only started in the mid-1990s and, thus, haven't finished the approval process, yet. One of those. ;-)

Comment: @curiousdannii It's terrible to park there - first you pull into the stall, then you pull out and try backing in, then you pull out again and pull in like normal and you can finally park your car.

Comment: @corsiKa I thought it was a new type of [craft](http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/nasa_2268_33073724) they were building.

Comment: All joking aside, since I don't have the foggiest what the USB facility would be, I asked [a new question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28194/8983).

Comment: @Mast Ah yes, that new craft is designed for a high speed transfer... orbit...

Comment: [The most recent version of the CCAFS map (Nov 2017)](https://twitter.com/julia_bergeron/status/1017805270406352896)