# Which has been the most gregarious rocket, launched from the most sites?

Tags: launch, launch-site

Which orbital launch vehicle has been "getting around" the most? Which rocket has put things in orbit from the largest number of different launch sites?

For the purposes of this question, allow for some flexibility; adding an extra side booster doesn't necessarily make it a different rocket. Two launch adjacent launch pads don't count as different sites, but Cape Canaveral Air Force Station and KSC would be different.

Launches from mobile launch platforms (on the ocean or land) shouldn't necessarily be counted as different just because each launch coordinate is slightly different, but use of different ports, or substantially different areas at sea would.

Comment: I like this question and it definitely has a canonical answer as of this point in spacetime.  However, I’m concerned that the answer to this question is likely to change over time.  Perhaps there is a way to modify this question so that the answer withstands the test of time...

Comment: @Paul on second thought, I think that's the right thing to do, and it only took a minor edit. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to add a community wiki answer, but the question edit makes it moot.  See template here in meta: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1091/26446

Comment: @DrSheldon sorry about that. I really like com-wiki's, and that would have been a good, *probably better* thing to do than my edit "...so that the answer withstands the test of time..."

Comment: @DrSheldon then again...

Comment: The Apollo Lunar Module has put itself into orbit from a number of lunar sites, which seems like it should be notable.  I'll let someone more learned decide if that's within the scope of this question.

Comment: @Roger I would certainly consider that a good answer. I've mentioned that interpretation should be flexible, and launch from an airplane is something I didn't expect but it certainly fits. Launch from the Moon is at least from the surface of a body, much more of a launch site than an airplane's underbelly. I'd say just go for it in this case.

Comment: Is it the distance between pads that is important in counting "two adjacent pads" or their administrative owners? See my comment on Antzi's answer. The two soyuz pads at Baikonur are rather further apart than the two Falcon 9 pads on Merrit Island.

Comment: @Puffin I'm using something like $d_{tot}=d_{t}+d_{ap}$ where $d$ stands for distance measured in "difficulty" units. There is both *transportation difficulty* or $d_t$ which measures how hard and far it would be to change your mind and move a rocket from one site to the other, and *administrative and programatic difficulty* which is sort-of self explanatory and redundant. Looking at [...difference between Cape Canaveral and Kennedy Space Center?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28149/12102) it sounds like it wouldn't be so easy to change your mind at the last minute and move between sites.

Comment: @Puffin [How far is Cape Canaveral from Kennedy Space Center, administratively and programmatically?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31884/12102)

Comment: This would be a good place to use the word "promiscuous" instead of "gregarious".

Comment: @RedSonja I'd thought about working "[strap-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_(rocketry)#Strap-on)" in there somehow, in place of "adding an extra side booster" but then I thought it just got weird.

Answer (score 64):

The [Apollo Lunar Module](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/50-years-ago-the-apollo-lunar-module) has launched from [six lunar sites](https://airandspace.si.edu/explore-and-learn/topics/apollo/apollo-program/landing-missions/sites.cfm):

Apollo 11 — Mare Tranquillitatis

Apollo 12 — Oceanus Procellarum

Apollo 14 — Fra Mauro

Apollo 15 — Hadley/Apennines

Apollo 16 — Descartes

Apollo 17 — Taurus-Littrow

Comment: Great! Launch sides on good-old *Terra firma* oh, that's *Luna firma* in this case. At least none of this air or water launching; these are real, solid launch sites, equipped with real launch platforms

Comment: Launching from a _Mare_ scores half a point for water launch.

Comment: Super answer! +1

Comment: And then I thought the air launch was cheating ...

Comment: Technically correct -- the best kind of correct! (Usually when I make this comment I don't mean it as a compliment, but this is the exception.)

Comment: Plus one "air" launch (Apollo 10).

Comment: I'm not sure if Apollo 10 'Snoopy' should count.  As I understand it, it 'launched' from lunar orbit into a different lunar orbit, and eventually the ascent part ended up in solar orbit.  Counting these sorts of orbital manoeuvres might open the question up way too much.  But I'm mildly undecided.

Comment: If you list Apollo 10, you should list also Apollo 5. Both the descent and ascent stage of the LM were used.

Comment: ^ and 9 - it also launched as it were

Answer (score 37):

Thanks to [Vikki - formerly Sean](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/23891/vikki-formerly-sean) who pointed out that not one, but two east central Florida airstrips were used.

[Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)#Launch_statistics), whose carrier plane has lifted off from

1. Edwards AFB
2. Cape Canaveral Air Force Station skid strip
3. Wallops Flight Facility
4. Base Aerea de Gando, Gran Canaria, Spain
5. Vandenberg AFB
6. Kwajalein Atoll
7. Kennedy Space Center's Shuttle Landing Facility ([SCD-1](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2665&context=smallsat))

on successful space launch missions.

[image]

Comment: Aha! I totally forgot about air-launches, but indeed this jet-setting rocket certainly "gets around" quite a bit.

Comment: @RonJohn I think they kinda ground ruled this out: "Launches from mobile launch platforms (on the ocean or land) shouldn't necessarily be counted as different just because each launch coordinate is slightly different, " (although air launch isn't *specifically* listed, I thought this applied)

Comment: Make that _seven_ "launch site"s; one Pegasus flight took off from KSC ([SCD-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sat%C3%A9lite_de_Coleta_de_Dados#SCD-1) in February 1993, the third-ever Pegasus launch).

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean ,thanks ! I listed the Cape already. I'll see if flights left from more than one airstrip in east central Florida.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: The OP specifically lists CCAFS and KSC as an example of two launch sites that are close but separate.

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean I'll have to check between the skid strip, SLF, and Patrick.

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean you're right, thanks! I found documents that confirmed use of both the SLF and the skid strip.  Beers on me.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: PDF link is broken.

Answer (score 34):

The **Soyuz** booster have been launched from:

- Baikonur
- Plesetsk
- Kourou
- Vostochny

Making it the only rocket to have been launched from 3 (4 if you count USSR) different countries and 3 different continents !

Contenders would be: the **Falcon 9**, launched from

- Kennedy Space Center
- Vandenberg Air Force Base
- Cape Canaveral

Tied with **Minotaur IV**  and **Athena 1**

- Vandenberg Air Force Base
- Kodiak
- Cape Canaveral

Comment: you count KSC and Cape Canaveral as 2 sites?

Comment: @Hobbes I wouldn't, but OP specified they should be treated as different spaceports.

Comment: Soyuz has been launched from Plesetsk as well. If you count the number of distinct pads its 8: 4 at Plesetsk, some decomissioned now, 2 at Baikonur and one at each of the other two. Complicated, because I think the Russian pads are at the same base but not "adjacent" in the terms of the OP question.

Comment: @Puffin I had totally forgotten about this ! Since they share the same name I think we can consider them as the same spaceport?

Comment: The two Soyuz R7 pads at Baikonur, according to my sums from their wiki pages, are 19km apart. KSC pad 39 and CCAFS pad 40 are just under 6km apart. Its more complex at Plesetsk as some of the four R7 pads are closer (400m), some further apart (8km). I've asked the OP to preside!

Comment: I would argue that Plesetsk is in Europe while Vostochny and Baikonur are in Asia. So together with Kourou (which is in South America unless you want to call it  Europe because France is in the European Union) that makes 3 continents.

Comment: For KSC versus Cape Canaveral see [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31856/which-has-been-the-most-gregarious-rocket-launched-from-the-most-sites?noredirect=1#comment96637_31856). new question: [How far is Cape Canaveral from Kennedy Space Center, administratively and programmatically?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31884/12102)

Comment: @Antzi The OP comments to the original question seems to indicate that purpose of this question its the administrative distance that is more interesting. i.e. if you had to cart your LV and satellite from one pad to another the distance wouldn't be as big a deal as the ownership for CCAFS/KSC and so, presumably means that the 19km between the two Baikonur R7 pads is not so interesting here either. Mind you, that's as the crow flies, I've no idea what the rail distance is!

Answer (score 14):

[Scout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Scout_launches):

- KSC
- Vandenberg
- Wallops
- [San Marco platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center) (owned by Italy, off the coast of Kenya)

Comment: yes, that's the one

Comment: not so fast ! It’s a tie with the Soyuz, see my edit thanks to Puffin :-)

Comment: Kerbal Space Center is a fictional location... wait... oh. I've been playing that game too much, haven't I?

Comment: [Where is the San Marco Launch Platform now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33182/12102)