# Help decoding the US Space Force 45th Space Wing emblem symbology

Tags: identify-this-object, insignia, space-force

[What is the difference between Cape Canaveral SFS and Patrick SFB?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51744/12102) reminds us that the US Space Force now has bases or at least stations. Wikipedia's [Cape Canaveral Space Force Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Space_Force_Station) links to the image below which is an inexact replica of what is shown on the official [45th Space Wing photos](https://www.patrick.spaceforce.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Article/329833/45th-space-wing/) web page (also [here](https://www.patrick.spaceforce.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2000207582/).

The page provides a high resolution download and says *commercial use* is no allowed without permission. I take that to mean that including a cropped detail for non-commercial use will be okay, so I've included that below as well.

**Questions:**

1. I see both an interleaved right and inverted "T" pattern crossing in blue and yellow, and what look like a two parallel rows of white ovals connected with short line segments in white. What do these signify, how do they relate to the mission of the 45th Space Wing? (tell me it's not a zipper on a space suit!)
2. The red arrows show what may be a launch trajectory around the Earth and towards cis-lunar space perhaps (they end somewhere near what might be a larger than proportional Moon). Is there any specific symbolism beyond simply "We send stuff to space"?

---

[image: detail from 45th Space Wing's emblem page https://www.patrick.spaceforce.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2000207582/]

**above:** detail, cropped from [Source](https://www.patrick.spaceforce.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2000207582/) **below:** [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:45th_Space_Wing.png)

[image: 45th Space Wing emblem from Wikimedia]

Comment: insignia yes, mission-patch no would be my 2 cents.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've been googling: [1](http://capemuseumgiftshop.org/45th-Space-Wing-pat), [2](https://www.ebay.com/itm/AUTHENTIC-45TH-SPACE-WING-AIR-FORCE-NASA-SPACEX-USAF-SPACE-OPERATIONS-PATCH/222417461642)

Comment: not associated with a particular mission

Comment: @OrganicMarble oic, patch $\ne$ mission patch, I've removed the tag, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heraldry is interpreted as follows:

- an interleaved right and inverted "T" pattern crossing in blue and yellow,

> a line of “Ts” representing continuous testing of space vehicles

- two parallel rows of white ovals connected with short line segments in white

> A string of white “clouds” across the center of the large globe represented abnormal conditions weather and radiation with which range personnel had to contend. The cloud symbol was also interpreted as the string of radomes and theodolites located throughout the Eastern Range.

- The red arrows show what may be a launch trajectory around the Earth and towards cis-lunar space perhaps

> Nine pimento red flight arrows indicated the normal equatorial departure routes for missiles and space vehicles on the Eastern Range. They also symbolized travel to other planets, as depicted by the smaller globe. Red was chosen for the flight arrows to indicate the stresses of launch and space flight and the heat of reentry into Earth’s atmosphere.

The Wing's emblem is derived from that of the Air Force Eastern Test Range (ETR). [A description of the ETR emblem](https://afspacemuseum.org/facilities/organization-and-installation-name-history/) contained the explanations.

[image]